# General way of debugging vmware mouse issues in X11

Tags: x11, xorg, vmware

I run a virtual vmware archlinux installation, and constantly have problems with mouse grab/ungrab. At some point it was fixed by commenting out pointer lines in 10-evdev config, but on every update there's different sort of problem, and the only way I know to address them is to try all sorts of tweaks, and see if one of them works. The log file is sometimes helpful, but sometimes confusing.

This gets annoying. I am searching for generic way to debug the mouse problem. With that, can someone tell me:

- How do I tell: which mouse driver(s) the X server is currently using?
- How do I tell: which OTHER mouse driver the X server loaded but not using?
- Whether vmware driver is even loaded?